# Spring Batch: Job execution details not getting inserted in Spring batch default tables

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

Iam new to Spring Batch and Spring cloud data flow. I have configured my job in config class and my job is executed by an api call. Iam using job launcher to launch the job.I have connected to a Mysql instance, Hence Spring Batch framework creates default tables in my DB. My issue is that the values for the tables are not getting inserted. I have ran my Job and i could see my job get completed by referring logs. But the execution details are not inserted in the tables. Help me with the issue. Here is my config class and yml file.

```
package com.acheron.batch.config;

import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import 
org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.
annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.
configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.
core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.
core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.
explore.support.MapJobExplorerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.
repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.IteratorItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.
support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import com.acheron.batch.vo.Contents;
import com.acheron.batch.vo.Schedules;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing

 public class BatchConfiguaration {
 @Autowired
private DataSource datasouce;

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public Environment env;

@Bean(name = "reader")
@StepScope
public ItemReader<Schedules> reader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[scheduleRecs]}") List<Schedules> scherecs) {
    ItemReader<Schedules> reader = new IteratorItemReader<Schedules>(scherecs);
    return reader;
}

@Bean(name = "CWSreader")
@StepScope
public ItemReader<Contents> CWSreader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[scheduleRecs]}") List<Contents> scherecs) {
    ItemReader<Contents> reader = new IteratorItemReader<Contents>(scherecs);
    return reader;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Bean
@StepScope
public BatchProcessor processor() {
    return new BatchProcessor();
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Bean
@StepScope
public ContentWorkflowBatchProcessor CWSprocessor() {
    return new ContentWorkflowBatchProcessor();
}


@Bean(name = "batchSchedulePreparedStatement")
@StepScope
public BatchSchedulePreparedStatement batchSchedulePreparedStatement() {
    return new BatchSchedulePreparedStatement();
}

@Bean(name = "contentWorkflowPreparedStatement")
@StepScope
public ContentWorkflowPreparedStatement contentWorkflowPreparedStatement() {
    return new ContentWorkflowPreparedStatement();
}

@Bean(name = "ContentWorkflowBatchWriter")
@StepScope
public ContentWorkflowBatchWriter ContentWorkflowBatchWriter() {
    return new ContentWorkflowBatchWriter();
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
@Bean(name = "batchWriter")
@StepScope
public BatchWriter batchWriter() {
    BatchWriter batchWriter = new BatchWriter();
    batchWriter.setDataSource(datasouce);
    batchWriter.setSql(env.getProperty("batch.insert.schedule.query"));
    batchWriter.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(batchSchedulePreparedStatement());
    return batchWriter;

}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
@Bean(name = "CWSbatchWriter")
@StepScope
public ContentWorkflowBatchWriter CWSbatchWriter() {
    ContentWorkflowBatchWriter contentWorkflowBatchWriter = new ContentWorkflowBatchWriter();
    contentWorkflowBatchWriter.setDataSource(datasouce);
    contentWorkflowBatchWriter.setSql(env.getProperty("batch.insert.contentworkflow.query"));
    contentWorkflowBatchWriter.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(contentWorkflowPreparedStatement());
    return contentWorkflowBatchWriter;

}

@Bean("acheronDbTm")
@Qualifier("acheronDbTm")
public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager() {
    return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
}

@Bean
public JobExplorer jobExplorer() throws Exception {
    MapJobExplorerFactoryBean explorerFactoryBean = new MapJobExplorerFactoryBean();
    explorerFactoryBean.setRepositoryFactory(mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean());
    explorerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return explorerFactoryBean.getObject();
}

@Bean
public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean() {
    MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(platformTransactionManager());
    return mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
    return mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean().getObject();
}

@Bean
public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher() throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository());
    return jobLauncher;
}

@Bean(name = "batchPartition")
@StepScope
public BatchPartition batchPartition() {
    BatchPartition batchPartition = new BatchPartition();
    return batchPartition;
}

@Bean(name = "contentWorkflowPartition")
@StepScope
public ContentWorkflowPartition ContentWorkflowPartition() {
    ContentWorkflowPartition contentWorkflowPartition = new ContentWorkflowPartition();
    return contentWorkflowPartition;
}

@Bean(name="taskExecutor")
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor poolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    poolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    poolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(30);
    poolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(35);
    poolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("Acheron");
    poolTaskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
    return poolTaskExecutor;
}

@Bean(name="CWSTaskExecutor")
public TaskExecutor CWSTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor poolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    poolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    poolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(30);
    poolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(35);
    poolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("Acheron");
    poolTaskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
    return poolTaskExecutor;
}

@Bean(name = "masterStep")
public Step masterStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep").partitioner(slave()).partitioner("slave", batchPartition())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor()).build();
}

@Bean(name = "CWSmasterStep")
public Step CWSmasterStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("CWSmasterStep").partitioner(CWSslave())
            .partitioner("CWSslave", ContentWorkflowPartition()).taskExecutor(CWSTaskExecutor()).build();
}

@Bean(name = "slave")
public Step slave() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("slave").chunk(100).faultTolerant().retryLimit(2)
            .retry(DeadlockLoserDataAccessException.class).reader(reader(null)).processor(processor())
            .writer(batchWriter()).build();

}

@Bean(name = "CWSslave")
public Step CWSslave() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("CWSslave").chunk(100).faultTolerant().retryLimit(2)
            .retry(DeadlockLoserDataAccessException.class).reader(CWSreader(null)).processor(processor())
            .writer(CWSbatchWriter()).build();

}

@Bean(name = "manageStagingScheduleMaster")
public Job manageStagingScheduleMaster(final Step masterStep) throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("manageStagingScheduleMaster").preventRestart().incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(masterStep).build();
 @Bean(name = "manageContentWorkflowStaging")
public Job manageContentWorkflowStaging(final Step CWSmasterStep) throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("manageContentWorkflowStaging").preventRestart()
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).start(CWSmasterStep).build();
}
}`
```

My YML File:

```
    rest:
      api1: http://localhost:8888/v1/daq/schedule?sourceId=7&endDate=11/01/2018&page=1&pageSize=2
      api2: https://api.myjson.com/bins/1gm3ef
      ContentWorkflow: http://localhost:8085/v1/cwdata/programcontentgap?&
      responseCount: 10000
      contentWorkflowType: ContentWorkflow
    batch.insert.schedule.query: 'insert into clouddataflow.STAGING_SCHEDULE_MASTER (SCHEDULE_ID,SOURCE_ID,SOURCE_NAME,AIRING_TYPE_ID,AIRING_TYPE_NAME,CREATED_DATE,CREATED_USER,MODIFIED_DATE,MODIFIED_USER)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
    batch.insert.contentworkflow.query: 'insert into clouddataflow.CONTENT_WORKFLOW_STAGING (CONTENT_WORKFLOW_STAGING_ID,PROGRAM_ID,MASTER_TITLE,ORIGINAL_TITLE,PROGRAM_TYPE_ID,PROGRAM_TYPE_NAME,SOURCE_GROUP_ID,SOURCE_GROUP_NAME,REGION,PROGRAM_LANGUAGE,CW_STATUS,COPY_CULTURE,GENRES,KEYWORDS,AIR_DATE_TIME,IS_PROCESSED,CREATED_USER,CREATED_DATE,MODIFIED_USER,MODIFIED_DATE)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
    modifiedUser: admin
    threadCount: 10
    spring.acherondb.url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clouddataflow'
    spring.acherondb.uname: uname
    spring.acherondb.pwd: pwd
    spring.acherondb.dclassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    spring.acherondb.schema: clouddataflow
    spring.acherondb.showSql: true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    spring:
      batch:
        job:
          enabled: true
      datasource:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        hikari:
            jdbc-url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clouddataflow
            username: uname
            password: pwd
            driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
            connection-timeout: 300
            idle-timeout: 30
            minimum-idle: 10
            maximum-pool-size: 30
    logging:
      level:
        com.acheron: ERROR
      pattern:
        file: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {%thread} %-5level %logger{36} -%msg%n'
      file: application
      path: ./logs
    queueScheduleData:
      createUser: User1
      status: Success
      modifiedUser: User1
    status:
      success: Success
      completed: COMPLETED
```

Logs for my Job are,

29-12-2017 15:00:38.997 [http-nio-9191-exec-1] INFO 
                o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=manageContentWorkflowStaging]] launched with the following parameters: [{date=1514539838904}]
29-12-2017 15:00:39.022 [http-nio-9191-exec-1] INFO 
                o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep - Executing step: [CWSmasterStep]
29-12-2017 15:00:44.710 [http-nio-9191-exec-1] INFO 
                o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=manageContentWorkflowStaging]] completed with the following parameters: [{date=1514539838904}] and the following status: [COMPLETED].

Comment: have you checked the logs/console for any errors?

Comment: There are no relevant logs about the issue. I had added the logs after executing my job in post

Comment: Did you check the server logs?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Basically, the application is running on embedded tomcat. Those embedded tomcat logs also will be logged in my application logs file only?. I am using logback for logging all application-level logs. Where could I check server logs?